# Problem with Dropbox Folder - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dropbox

I have just installed Dropbox two days ago, but I can't find the Dropbox Folder. I had a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04, and when I installed Dropbox a folder appear in my "Home" folder.

I try to find it with the "find" command by terminal but didn't find it. Do you know how can I "activate" the folder?

Comment: After setting it up, I had to run the Python Script [from the bottom of the install page](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) in order to get the link to activate my account.  After that, dropbox showed up without a problem.